# Windows phone Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended.dll file

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I get Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended dll file for my project? I am unable to find this anywhere. Can someone help me?

Thanks
Jai

Comment: Check here http://aminespinoza.com/materialBlog/muestras/Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended.zip

Comment: What do you require the DLL specifically?

Comment: This? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202949(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be aware that this DLL is not a part of the public SDK, therefore **your application will not pass Marketplace certification** if it is using it. You can get it by dumping the emulator OS image, for example, to get the GAC.

Or you could use reflection. I worked on that [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/not-your-regular-photo-and).

**EDIT:** Since you need to access the flash, are you aware of this? It's been in Mango for a while now:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202949(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: Thanks Dennis Delimarsky. I was not aware of this issue.